# Which GhostScript command for PS scripting

Tags: ghostscript

I m using the command--->
C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.09\bin\gswin32 -q -dNOPAUSE  -sDEVICE=gswin32 -sOutputFile="\spool\PRINTER_NAME"  "FILE_NAME" -c quit
for printing through ghostscript. what should i use in place of -sDEVICE=gswin32
for PS Scripting

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'PS scripting'.

However, it looks like you want to use Ghostscript to interpret PostScript programs (or PDF files) and send the rendered result of interpreting the program to the Windows Printing System, in order to send it to a printer supported by Windows.

In which case you need the mswinpr2 device.

This is covered in the [documentation](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.22/Devices.htm#Win) To be honest I'm somewhat surprised that you had managed to get the OutputFile correct, but not the DEVICE.....